# How to create a new SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite, command

I am working on Mac OS X,
I want to create a new SQLite DB, and
I am using http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html as a reference.

I am entering: `sqlite3 test.db`
and getting the response:

```
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because that is the administrative shell prompt. The shell created test.db and is now waiting for you to do something with it thus the `sqlite>` prompt you see.

You may want to `create table ...` at this point.

Comment: Also, use `.exit` to exit. Very useful to know!

Comment: @JustCurious, test.db is stored in the folder where you issued the command. You can specify the full path of the database file as well, eg, sqlite3 /tmp/test.db.

Comment: Actually, it will  not create a db for you, until you create some table in it. You'll have to type `sqlite3 test.db ""`. And, btw, it's just an empty file - there is nothing special in it. You can create it any way you want.

Comment: @Keeprock you are correct, over five years after I wrote that answer, version 3.8.11.1 2015-07-29 of `sqlite3 test.db` alone will not create an empty `test.db`. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 29):

It worked. Quit out and test - the database has been created.

You are now in the SQLite shell, and it is ready to receive commands like `CREATE TABLE...`, `INSERT INTO...`, etc.

If you would prefer not to use the interactive shell, you can build your schema straight from the command line:

```
sqlite3 test.db "CREATE TABLE ..."
```

Or just create an empty database with no schema:

```
sqlite3 test.db ""
```

But that's the same as just creating an empty file, anyway:

```
touch test.db
```

Answer (score 2):

so it is fine. you are prompted to enter commands. create table, insert, select. have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You're being taken to the SQLite prompt (where you can create tables, add data, etc.). Nothing appears out of the ordinary based on what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

For example, running SQLite3 with the new database name `mydb.sqlite3` and creating the table `person` as shown below can create the new database `mydb.sqlite3`:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3
...
sqlite> CREATE TABLE person(id integer, name text);
```

And, you can do the above with one line of command as shown below:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 'CREATE TABLE person(id integer, name text)'
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 "CREATE TABLE person(id integer, name text)"
```

Be careful, only running SQLite3 with the new database name `mydb.sqlite3` as shown below cannot create the new database `mydb.sqlite3`:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3
```

In addition, you can create the empty database `mydb.sqlite3` with `''` or `""` as shown below:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 ''
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 ""
```