# Generating tables for INSTALLED_APPS fails

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", lin
e 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", lin
e 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 19
6, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 23
2, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 37
1, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.p
y", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 30
6, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", lin
e 281, in _cursor
    self._sqlite_create_connection()
  File "D:\PythonPack\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", lin
e 271, in _sqlite_create_connection
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I run into those error after trying out

```
python manage.py syncbd
```

in this tutorial 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

to start the first web application with Django (Dian-go or Jan-go ?).
Could someone help me what caused those error messages ?

**UPDATE**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'D:\Python\mysite\sqlitedb',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

That is the DB settings

Comment: Have you properly configured your database settings? It appears you're using SQLite3 but does it indeed create a database file when you run that command?

Comment: I update to clarify. It doesn't create any db files at all, instead it displays the above errors

Comment: Create a [database file first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629835/create-new-sqlite-db).

Comment: Django should be able to create the database file on its own. Can Django actually write in the directory where you want the database file to be?

Answer (score 0):

Windows users should use / instead of \ for file paths in settings.py.
Use `D:/Python/mysite/sqlitedb` instead of `D:\Python\mysite\sqlitedb`.