# How to create an empty SQLite db with command?

Tags: database, sqlite, command

Is it possible to create an empty `sqlite3` database from the command line (e.g. `sqlite3 <someoption> dbname`) which would create a database file for me empty of any tables so that I can access it from a different SQL editor?

Currently, when I do `sqlite3 dbname`, I get a sqlite prompt from which I can do `CREATE TABLE ...` but if I don't, when I exit, no file is created.  So I am looking for a single command which would create an empty database for me without a need to create at least one table within that step.

Comment: You mean to create on iPhone? If you are looking for initializing database, take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated

Comment: `sqlite3 a.db ""` creates empty file

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that in just one statement.

In Linux I would workaround it this way:

```
sqlite3 aFile.db "create table aTable(field1 int); drop table aTable;"
```

This will automatically create the needed file with the table in it and then drop it leaving the database file without tables. That's the closest thing I know.

Anyway, I think most editors will even accept an empty file too. Give that a try.

Comment: this creates an empty file - thus, all editors will have to accept an empty file

Answer (score 89):

Use the [VACUUM command](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) to create a valid empty SQLite database file, including the root [database page](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#pages) and the [database header](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header).

```
sqlite3 file.db "VACUUM;"
```

Comment: tried this and the selected answer - this is half the size!

Comment: That’s a good tip, but is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @Manngo Kind of. The [official documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) says: `The VACUUM command rebuilds the database file.` And in this specific case, we're just simply (re)building an empty database file.

Comment: @emkey08 I saw the documentation on `VACUUM`. I couldn’t find the part where the `sqlite3` command could take the extra parameter.

Comment: That's documented [here](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#using_sqlite3_in_a_shell_script), where it says that "sqlite3 allows a single SQL command to be entered on the command line as a second argument after the database name".

Answer (score 31):

The simple way is in bash, use command

```
touch file.db
```

This will just create a 0 size file and can be used as an empty sqlite file.

Answer (score 26):

You can also call .databases when you enter the command prompt.

Or:

```
sqlite3 test.db ".databases"
```

Answer (score 20):

Just create an empty file.

```
> test.db
```

Symbol ">" here means redirection.

Comment: This actually works and does the same as all the complex answers above. For future compatibility, you might do ".databases", though...

Answer (score 2):

Creating a blank db like this ( provided by [mosty-mostacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho) ) has an advantage of being recognised as a valid SQLite db; better than an empty file.

```
$sqlite3 foo.db "create table t(f int); drop table t;"
```

Verify it by :

```
$file foo.db 
foo.db: SQLite 3.x database, last written using SQLite version 3024000
```

Answer (score 0):

from https://sqlite.org/cli.html

> Start the sqlite3 program by typing "sqlite3" at the command prompt,
> optionally followed by the name the file that holds the SQLite
> database (or ZIP archive). **If the named file does not exist, a new
> database file with the given name will be created automatically.** If no
> database file is specified on the command-line, a temporary database
> is created and automatically deleted when the "sqlite3" program exits.

my emphasis

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can create the empty database `mydb.sqlite3` with `''` or `""` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629835/create-new-sqlite-db/77189165#77189165) explains how to create a SQLite database:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 ''
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 ""
```

Be careful, you cannot create the empty database `mydb.sqlite3` without `''` or `""` as shown below:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3
```